# asp.net core 2.0 GitHub has with GetExternalLoginInfoAsync

Tags: github, oauth, asp.net-core

I config service for GitHub

```chsarp
services.AddOAuth("GitHub", "Github", o =>
{
    o.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:GitHub:ClientId"];
    o.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:GitHub:ClientSecret"];
    o.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-github");
    o.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize";
    o.TokenEndpoint = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token";
    o.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.github.com/user";
    o.ClaimsIssuer = "OAuth2-Github";
    o.SaveTokens = true;
    // Retrieving user information is unique to each provider.
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "login");
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:name", "name");
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email", ClaimValueTypes.Email);
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:url", "url");
    o.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
        {
            // Get the GitHub user
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            context.RunClaimActions(user);
        }
    };
});
```

When I login on GitHub I redirect to action and in action has line ...

```chsarp
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();//return null
```

That line always return null. 
Can you help me?

Comment: I found solution on http://jameschambers.com/2016/04/github-authentication-asp-net-core/

Comment: But I want to know what happend in background when user loggin from social network...